# How to access the elements inside the shadowdom

Tags: angular, dom, shadow-dom, angular7

I just want to access the elements inside the shadow-root.
In my Angular application, one of my component is encapsulated with **shadowDom**.

```
@component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./home.component.scss"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
```

when I serve the application, this is how the rendered elements looks like

```
<body class>
  <app-root _nghost-c0 ng-version="7.0.3">
    <router-outlet _ngcontent-c1=""></router-outlet>
      <app-home>
      #shadow-root (open)                                                 <== shadow-root
        <style>...</style>
        <style>...</style>
        <div id="main">
          <section id="one">
            <app-github-calendar _nghost-c3>
               <div _ngcontent-c3 class="calendar"> Loading the data just  <== this element
               for you.</div>
            </app-github-calendar>
          </section> 
      </app-home>
```

I tried to get the *"calendar"* element usign javascript **querySelector**, **getElementsByClassName**, **querySelectorAll** etc. 
but I cant get element.

Tell me how to get that.

Comment: What does your code look like? If you want to get at something in shadowDOM then you need to use `el.shadowRoot.querySelector()`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package to do just that.

```
npm install --save-dev deep-query-selector-all
```

Then this example code should work:

```
import {deepQuerySelectorAll} from "deep-query-selector-all";

const calendarElements = deepQuerySelectorAll(".calendar");
```